# How to make this nested summation efficient in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, sum

I have a problem making an efficient function to be used in a rootfinding algorithm. I need to make a function that is a triple summation over lables, which contains a triple summation over a pair of lists. I have already tried several implementations such as using nested lists, dictionaries, splitting the inner triple summation in two double summations (with an intermediate lists), keeping the 'm' & 'n' dictionaries/lists apart, using itertools.izip() to go over R and E together and probably a few others I'm forgetting.

The idea is that I need to be able to discriminate the labels for other functions, so I need an efficient way to store, access and sum over these sets of numbers.

Now, this function is part of an iteration, so the first time, most of these lists are empty. Then I need to use a rootfinding algorithm(pretty simple) for each value in the E-dictionary. After using a root finding algorithm (which depends on this function), the lists are refilled with its solutions. This means that in the second iteration each list will contain about the order of 1000 numbers. After that the rootfinding is again used with this new function, giving (after rebinning) 1000 new numbers in each list.

Clearly I have a problem if this rootfinding already takes several minutes in the first iteration. I have a specific implementation for the first iteration (which is reduced to 3 loops over the labels because of all the empty/only one value in list stuff) which finds all these roots in two seconds.

How can I do this summation efficiently, while still being able to discriminate between the various lists?

Thanks in advance

Note: this code is not my most beautifull attempt, but it is the most clear in what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
E = {}
R = {}
for i in labels:
    E[i] = {'m':[i], 'n':[]}    #the label happens to be the value that's in here
    E[-i] = {'m':[], 'n':[-i]}
    R[i] = {'m':[1], 'n':[]}
    R[-i] = {'m':[], 'n':[1]}

def function(A, En):
    temp = 0
    for a in E:
        if (not(ACTIVATE) or a != A):
            for b in E:
                for c in E:
                    if ( not(ACTIVATE) or b != c):
                        for i in xrange(len(R[a]['n'])):
                            for j in xrange(len(R[b]['m'])):
                                for k in xrange(len(R[c]['m'])):
                                    temp += R[a]['n'][i]*R[b]['m'][j]*R[c]['m'][k]/(En - (-E[a]['n'][i] + E[b]['m'][j] + E[c]['m'][k]))
                        for i in xrange(len(R[a]['m'])):
                            for j in xrange(len(R[b]['n'])):
                                for k in xrange(len(R[c]['n'])):
                                    temp += R[a]['m'][i]*R[b]['n'][j]*R[c]['n'][k]/(En + (E[a]['m'][i] - E[b]['n'][j] - E[c]['n'][k]))
    return .5*temp
```

Comment: You mean `for c in E` instead of `for v in E`, right? And at the end, you mean `return .5*temp` instead, right?

Comment: Yes, indeed, thanks for that! Some errors in trying to make the naming more simple.